# MongoDB & Mongoose: How do I get the index of the removed item when using pull?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have to remove an item from an array of subschemas in a document.

```
SubSchema = new mongoose.Schema({...})
MySchema = new mongoose.Schema({someArray: [SubSchema]})
(...)
mydoc.somearray.pull(req.body.submodel_id);
```

However, I need the index of the element that has been removed to notify all connected clients.

Is there an elegant solution to this, or do I have to use `_.findIndex` or something like that? (I imagine that to have worse performance since it unnecessarily iterates the array twice)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if an elegant solution exists for this as MongoDB has no way of returning the index of the array element
being pulled within an update operation. One approach (though I would consider it a dirty hack) would be to get the original
array after the update operation and get the removed element index using **[`Array.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)** within the update callback.

Consider the following update operation using **[`findOneAndUpdate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-findOneAndUpdate)** to get the update document:

```
var submodel_id = req.body.submodel_id,
    query = { "someArray": submodel_id };

Model.findOneAndUpdate(
    query,
    { "$pull": { "someArray": submodel_id } },
    { "new": false },
    function(err, doc) {
        var removedIndex = doc.someArray.indexOf(submodel_id);
        console.log(removedIndex);
    }
);
```

Comment: That still searches the doc twice, doesn't it? (once for pull and once for indexOf)
I think it's rather odd that mongoDB & mongoose don't support deletion by index (which would solve my problem)
Thanks anyway.

Comment: @ClaasM. No it doesn't search twice, the above update operation uses the MongoDB's findAndModify() API which queries the collection once and the {new: false} option returns the original unmodified document in the callback.

Comment: I was speaking of `IndexOf`. It just seems so unnecessary to query someArray for submodel_id and then use `IndexOf` to iterate someArray _again_ to find the correct index.